# MS Access Auto Populate form based upon a different field's selection

Tags: ms-access

I have a couple of tables in my database.

workout_moves - ID, workout Type, Exercise, Reps
session_moves - ID, Exercise(from workout_moves table), Weight, Notes

I have created a form called workout session which has created a subform for the session_moves table.

The session_moves subform looks like this :

[image]

This is fine -but when I select my exercise from the list, I want it to autopopulate the associated Reps value from the workout_moves table rather than forcing me to pick from the list, which is not quite what I would like.

As you can see in the workout_moves table, each exercise is matched to a reps column so this should be pretty easy:

[image]

I just cannot work out what the "Row Source" should be for the Reps column in this form in order to auto pull in the data associated with the selection in the Exercise column. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the control source to

```vb
=Dlookup("Reps";"workout_moves";"[workout Type] = '" & Nz(cboExercise;"") & "'")
```

in the Reps control. `cboExercise` is the controlname of the exercise combobox.

Think about changing foreignkey in table `session_moves` from Exercises to ID (use primarykeys as foreignkeys).

Comment: It says the expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You omitted an operand or operator?

Comment: @Renegade Typo! Should be `Nz(cboExercise;"")`. Outside vba separator is `;` not `,`!

Comment: corrected several typos and wrong field name `[workout Type]`! Works for me in a test db.

Comment: can you share this test db? I am still getting syntax issues.

Comment: make sure the name of the combox is `cboExercise`! Table and field names fit (Reps,workout_moves,[workout Type])? Show the datatypes of the fields in the tables!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111291/discussion-between-renegadeandy-and-bitaccesser).